# Laravel set Pdf Protection

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to make a function in laravel 5.5 to set a password on a PDf file. I tried it by using library

```
use setasign\FpdiProtection\FpdiProtection;
$pdf = new FpdiProtection();
          $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($request->file('file'));
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
        $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($i);
      
        $specs = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplidx);
      
        $pdf->addPage($specs['orientation'], [ $specs['width'], $specs['height'] ]);
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
    }
    $pdf->setProtection(
        FpdiProtection::PERM_PRINT | FpdiProtection::PERM_COPY,
        'the user password',
        'the owner password'
    );

    $pdf->save($FilePathPdf);
```

But it is not working.
it give following error

> message: Type error: Argument 1 passed to setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi::getPdfParserInstance() must be an instance of setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader, instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile given, called in /home/mumar/Projects/ilovepdf/vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/FpdiTrait.php on line 178

Comment: The exception tells the problem: It's looking for something, but gets something else. In other words, the request gives an `UploadedFile` object, but it [appears to need](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI/blob/67dfce5d9706be0ce4750b0c18d6aea5162866fe/src/FpdiTrait.php#L208) one of these: `string|resource|StreamReader`. @MihaiCrăiță answer solves that problem by providing the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the file path:

```
$pdf->setSourceFile($request->file('file')->path());
```